# How to reference int pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

How to reference an integer pointer in C++ (visual studio), something like:

```
int * ptr = 5;
std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

Without getting the error: identifier `ptr` is undefined

Comment: Please post an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And please get into the habit of stating the compiler you are using, and copy & paste the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "reference an integer pointer" which sounds to me like:

```
int* ptr = new int;
*ptr=5;
int*& ref_to_ptr = ptr;
```

However, I do not think you meant that. You meant something like this:

```
int* ptr = new int(5);
std::cout << *ptr;
```

When you assign `5` to ptr directly without `new`, you are trying to give it an address rather than a value. Pointers holds an address to some place where the value exist rather than holding a direct value.

See this for more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ptr=new int(5);
```

or you can have the declaration and initalization in different statements

```
int *ptr=new int( );
*ptr=5;
```

Comment: There are many more ways to make `ptr` valid.